# How can I install tkinter for Python on Mac?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I posted this error on a Facebook group, they said I should get pip. I installed pip, when I am wanting to install tkinter it's giving me error:

I used this command first :

```
sudo pip install tkinter

.
.
.
error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

Comment: You can't install tkinter with pip. Whoever told you that you could is wrong.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After a day of headache, this worked for me:

```
$ brew install python-tk
```

Comment: `pip install tk` won't work for me, but `brew install python-tk` did.

Comment: pip install tk will install TensorKit, not tkinter.

Comment: You are the man!

Comment: Note for the future: `brew install python-tk@3.12` for specific python versions (here 3.12).

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same issue:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

After quite a while I finally realized that I needed to install the python-tk package. On Linux all I needed to do was `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`.

Comment: Is that the exact error you received? From looking at https://askubuntu.com/questions/815874/importerror-no-named-tkinter-please-install-the-python3-tk-package, I would expect the more specific one.

Comment: That's the exact error I received from python when attempting to run: `import tkinter`

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is about macOS, not Linux, so this answer is not really relevant.